# Endless loop for Write a function first_n_evens(n) that returns an array of the first N many even numbers

Tags: arrays, ruby, if-statement, while-loop

I can't figure out how to correctly complete this question.

Write a function `first_n_evens(n)` that returns an array of the first N many even numbers, starting from 0.

Please help me understand what I am doing wrong.

Many Thanks

```
def first_n_evens(n)
  array = []
  number = 0

  while array.count <= n
    if number % 2 == 0
      array.push(number)
      number += 1
    end
  end

return array

end

test = first_n_evens(5)
puts test
```

Comment: Try `(0...(2*n)).step(2).to_a`.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
number += 1
```

Is inside of your `if` block.  If `number` is even, `number` gets incremented.  If `number` is odd, then the `if` condition isn't met, and nothing happens.

Move that line outside of the `if`..`end` block, and you should be okay.